# Django Sendgrid authentication error

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I am trying to authenticate myself via SendGrid API in order to work with templates Engine API (creating them for A/B testing), but no matter what, I am getting a 401 unauthorized error. Could someone help please? Am I doing something wrong ? This is my code:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Template)
def create_sendgrid_template(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates'
    sendgrid_data = {
        "name": "example_template",
    }
    if created:
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        base64string = base64.encodestring(
            '%s:%s' % (
                SENDGRID_API_USER,
                SENDGRID_API_PASSWORD)
            ).replace('\n', '')
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try encoding your data and adding it to the request — I suspect you're GETing rather than POSTing. See the [urllib howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#data). It's also worth verifying that your credentials are correct.

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Template)
def create_sendgrid_template(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates'
sendgrid_data = {
    "name": "example_template",
}
data = json.dumps(sendgrid_data)

if created:
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    base64string = base64.encodestring(
        '%s:%s' % (
            SENDGRID_API_USER,
            SENDGRID_API_PASSWORD)
        ).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    request.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')        
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

If you're not looking to roll your own solution, there are services like [sendwithus](https://www.sendwithus.com/) and [mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/) that do A/B testing on emails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately encoding the data did not work, for some reason, I am still getting the same error..

Comment: My mistake, the SendGrid API takes in JSON data. I've updated my example to reflect that.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work either. Although, I am able to login to the API using Curl via command line! I was also adviced to use `Requests` library instead of Pythons old `urllib2`, so I will update the answer soon.

Comment: @Eimantas That's so bizarre. This was my [code](https://gist.github.com/demoore/c561b929c7a2851748b8) and this was the result:

`{"name": "example_template2"}`
`[('Content-type', 'application/json'), ('Authorization', 'Basic base64string=')]`
`{"name": "example_template2"}`
`{"id":"227ace2c-6a59-4298-a8d2-aecdded0da3c","name":"example_template2","versions":[]}`

I think if you use an existing template name it will spit a 400 at you. Glad you figured it out though!

Comment: Unfortunately I did not figure it out yet, because the code doesn't work even if I make the request via `Requests` library. Django's development server is running on http and not on https, maybe that could be a problem?